# Trouble removing words containing a mix letters and numbers from string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I've succeeded in getting my code to remove floats and reverse the order of the input form the command line but I can't seem to get the final regex expression to successfully remove all words that contain non-digits or a mix of digits and non-digits. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import re


in_list = sys.argv



def int_sort(i):
    int_sort = "test"
    int_sort = in_list[1:]
    int_sort = " ".join(list(reversed(int_sort))) # sorts everything in reverse of input
    int_sort = re.sub('([0-9]*\.[1-9]+)', " ", int_sort).strip() #strips all floats from list
    int_sort = "".join(int_sort)
    int_sort = re.sub("\S+\D\S+", " ", int_sort).strip() # strips any word that contains anything but a number
    return(int_sort)
print (int_sort(in_list))
```

Results from command line:

```
$ testing abc 13 12ab cbds 1234 1.23 ab12

$
```

Desired results:

```
$ testing abc 13 12ab cbds 1234 1.23 ab12

$1234 13
```

Comment: Try [`" ".join(list(reversed(re.findall(r"(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)", "testing abc 13 12ab cbds 1234 1.23 ab12"))))`](http://ideone.com/cR21Qn). Or [`" ".join(list(reversed([s for s in in_list.split() if s.isdigit()])))`](http://ideone.com/bpwZ5k)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you overcomplicate the task. You may split the string with whitespaces and get the whole digit chunks and then reverse the list.

```
in_list = "testing abc 13 12ab cbds 1234 1.23 ab12"
in_list2 =  " ".join(list(reversed([s for s in in_list.split() if s.isdigit()])))
print(in_list2)
```

Else, you may use a `(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)` pattern to grab the digits that are enclosed with whitespace (with `re.findall`) and then reverse the list:

```
import re
in_list = "testing abc 13 12ab cbds 1234 1.23 ab12"
int_sort = " ".join(list(reversed(re.findall(r"(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)", in_list))))
print(int_sort)
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/bpwZ5k)

Comment: Thanks a lot Wiktor

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't realize I was at 15 rep yet.